# Show error message to check that PIN is valid or not in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want the PIN validation to occur only after the user has entered 4 digits, and I want to show whether the PIN is matched or not after the user has entered all four digits.

The current implementation validates the PIN as soon as each digit is entered.

[image]

[image]

**Here is my SetPinTestscreen:**

```
class _SetPinTestscreenState extends State<SetPinTestscreen> {
  TextEditingController setPinController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false).isPinSet = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _validatePin(String value) {
    Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .validatePin(value, setPinController);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainTemplate(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, pinProvider, child) {
                  return Text(
                    pinProvider.isPinSet
                        ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                        : 'Set PIN to Activate your Ending With XXXX',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: _validatePin,
                codeLength: 4,
                cursor: Cursor(color: Colors.black, enabled: true),
                controller: setPinController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                final textColor = provider.isPinSet == false
                    ? provider.isInvalidPin || !provider.isPinMatched
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black
                    : provider.isInvalidPin && !provider.isPinMatched
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black;

                if (!provider.isPinMatched &&
                    provider.isPinSet &&
                    setPinController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                    setPinController.text.length < 4) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'PIN does not match.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text(
                    'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
                    ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Here is my PinValidationProvider:**

```
   class PinValidationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isInvalidPin = false;

  bool get isInvalidPin => _isInvalidPin;

  bool get isPinMatched => confirmedPin == pin;
  bool isPinSet = false;
  String pin = '';
  String confirmedPin = '';

  void validatePin(String pin, TextEditingController controller) {
    if (pin.length != 4) {
      _isInvalidPin = false;
    } else {
      if (_isSimpleSequence(pin) || _isRepeatedDigit(pin)) {
        _isInvalidPin = true;
      } else {
        _isInvalidPin = false;
        if (!isPinSet) {
          isPinSet = true;
          this.pin = pin;
        } else {
          confirmedPin = pin;
        }
      }
      if (confirmedPin != this.pin) {
        controller.clear();
      }
    }
    Future.microtask(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  bool _isSimpleSequence(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      int digit1 = int.parse(pin[i]);
      int digit2 = int.parse(pin[i + 1]);

      if (digit2 - digit1 == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool _isRepeatedDigit(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pin[i] == pin[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you said:

```
if (!provider.isPinMatched &&
    provider.isPinSet &&
    setPinController.text.isNotEmpty &&
    setPinController.text.length < 4) 
         { return 'PIN does not match.'}
```

you should change the `setPinController.text.length < 4` to == 4 instead, that way it will show the message only when the length is 4

Comment: I tried this also, then error message doesn't show when i entered mis match PIN

Comment: what does it show after typing 4 incorrect pin? with my changes

Comment: Nothing, just the below message remain same `Pin must be at least 4....`

Comment: can you debugPrint(isPinSet) and make sure its true? same for the isPinMatched to return false, just want to make sure if one of these values are causing the issue

Comment: nothing show in console

Comment: I saw you did take your 4 values in a single controller. If you want to check individually, you've to take 4 controllers and store these individually. It'll help you to check pins easily.